# group by date, even if there is no entry for the date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I want to visualize my entries by counting how many have been created at the same day.

```
SELECT dayname(created_at), count(*) FROM logs
group by day(created_at)
ORDER BY created_at desc
LIMIT 7
```

So I get something like:

```
Thursday    4  
Wednesday   12  
Monday  4  
Sunday  1  
Saturday    20  
Friday  23  
Thursday    10
```

But I also want to have the Tuesday in there with 0 so I have it for one week.

Is there a way to do this with full mysql or do I need to update the result before I can give it to the chart?

**EDIT:**

This is the final query:

```
SELECT
    DAYNAME(date_add(NOW(), interval days.id day)) AS day,
    count(logs.id) AS amount
FROM days LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT *
    FROM logs
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,DATE(created_at),now()) < 7) logs
    on datediff(created_at, NOW()) = days.id
GROUP BY days.id
ORDER BY days.id desc;
```

The table days includes numbers from 0 to -6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a table of offsets which could be a real table or something built on the fly like `select 0 ofs union all select -1 ...`.

```
create table days (ofs int);
insert into days (ofs) values
     (0), (-1), (-2), (-3),
    (-4), (-5), (-6), (-7);

select
    date_add('20160121', interval days.ofs day) as created_at,
    count(data.id) as cnt
from days left outer join logs data
    on datediff(data.created_at, '20160121') = days.ofs
group by days.ofs
order by days.ofs;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e6bc7/1

For performance it would probably be better to limit the search in the data (logs) table:

```
select
    date_add('20160121', interval days.ofs day) as created_at,
    count(data.id) as cnt
from days left outer join
    (select * from logs where created_at between <start> and <end>) data
    on datediff(data.created_at, '20160121') = days.offset
group by days.offset
order by days.offset;
```

One downside is that you do have to parameterize this with a fixed anchor date in a couple of expressions. It might be better to have a table of real dates sitting in a table somewhere so you don't have to do the calculations.

Comment: @mimo Cool. Hopefully you took out the -7 if you didn't actually want to cover 8 days in your report.

Answer (score 0):

Use **RIGHT JOIN** to a dates table,  so you can request data for each and all days,  no matter if some days have data or not,  simply,  mull days will show as CERO or NULL.

You can create a dates table,  some sort of calendar table.

```
 id_day | day_date   |
 --------------------
 1      | 2016-01-01 |
 2      | 2016-01-02 |
 .
 .
 365    | 2016-12-31 |
```

With this table,  you can relate date,  then extract day, month, week, whatever you want with [MYSQL DATE AND TIME FUNCTIONS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
 SELECT t2.dayname(day_date), count(t1.created_at) FROM logs t1 right join dates_table t2 on t1.created_at=t2.day_date group by t2.day_date ORDER BY t1.created_at desc LIMIT 7
```

Comment: I only found left join examples with hard coded dates.

Comment: But isn't this just a little work around? I have to update this table every year, so can't i create a table on the fly that returns me the last 7 days?

Comment: It's up to you to create one time a year a yearly table with 365 rows, which can be done easily with a loop or to create every week a 7 day table.  What matters is that if no event is inserted for a given date on your logs table, there is no way to make that missing date appear without the help of an external table.  My opinion is that yearly tables are very helpful.   I learned from Kimaballs modelling books.

Comment: Yeah, I think the table including all dates is the best option. I tried it with only the week days, but then you can't order them.